# sales tax rate retreval from zip code

Tags: php

what are some popular 3rd party applications that i can use to retrieve the current sales tax rate from a zip code? i will be using php. i thought about building my own but after i noticed that the U.S. has 40k+ zip codes it wouldn't be easy. what are my options.

are they free or i have to pay monthly

thanks

Answer (score 1):

A zip code is not enough to determine sales tax, since the area covered can (and frequently does) span multiple tax jurisdictions.  You need a package that would retrieve it based on street address and zip code.  There are companies out there that would allow you to perform such queries via a web service, for a fee.  I am in the process of looking into https://www.taxdatasystems.net .  They charge between 7 and 15 cents per query, depending on monthly volume.

Answer (score 0):

How about work with the USPS and UPS Apis:
http://www.ups.com/content/us/en/bussol/browse/online_tools_shipping.html
https://www.usps.com/business/webtools.htm

You could totally just work with these and not have to worry about all the database work of inserting 40k zipcodes then writing php to work with them... try out these APIs

UPS's api looks a bit more mature